# Reading text from file and attaching to link in selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, fopen

I am trying to read text lines from a file and attach them to the end of a link and perform few actions then read next line and repeat same procedure.

This is what I have so far and appreciate any and all help!

```
url = "https://www.instagram.com/"
f = open("names.txt")
text1 = [text.strip() for text in f.readlines()]
for text in text1:
    browser.get(url(text1))
    print(url)
f.close
```

error I am receiving -

'str' object is not callable

Comment: What's the problem here?

Comment: Edited my original post with problem attached.

Comment: What does your text file contain? Usernames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the string first and then send it to browser.get()

Can you please check this code

```py
url = "https://www.instagram.com/"
f = open("names.txt")
text1 = f.readlines()
for text in text1:
    driver.get('{}{}'.format(url, text.strip()))
    print('{}{}'.format(url, text.strip()))
f.close()
```

I believe your txt file contains some Instagram usernames. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are right actually. It does contain usernames and this did actually make it work. I just  need to add sleep functions and create actions between each load now so thank you for this!